# How to pass a function in JS worklet post message call?

Tags: javascript, audio-worklet

I need my worklet to use a function that is in the calling TS file. Since in [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) only strings and numbers are allowed. I am finding it difficult to pass a function. Is this even possible ?

`calling.ts`

```
        // processAudio is the function (This is how i send data to worklet function)
        this.socketWorkletNode.port.postMessage({
            type: 'setState', state: state,
            processAudio: this.filterFunctions.processAudio
        });
```

`worklet.js`

```
class audio_process_worklet {
  ...
  handleMessage_(event) {
        // If process function is available then set it in the class
        if(event.data.processAudio) {
            this.processedData = event.data.processAudio(this.audioData);
        }
  }
  ...
}
```

**More details**: The reason i need to pass the function is because it is a function i got through WebAssembly. Its actually is a function written in C code. I compiled it as a  WASM file using emcc compiler and served the file from the server. Using WebAssembly module in the browser, i get the function.

Comment: You would have to include your WebAssembly as part of the code loaded into the worklet when you create it.

Comment: I am pretty new to worklets and WebAssembly. Do you have any example how it can be done ? I would help me a lot.
I tried to rum WebAssembly inside worklet itself. But it dint run as it said its undefined. But as per JS these are available globally right !!!